# Wpf Login System

Tags: wpf, authentication, system

i am developing a training software in wpf. but i have problems. this application will be setup project.

when the user make it work, a login window will open.  User should enter his username.there wont be a password.

**but the problem is next;** i dont know how to get userid from database. and compare other usernames to get the right userid.

**second problem is,** when i  get right userid from database, how can i use it main window? where can i store this userid. will be this session or something like that?

i want this userid because, user will have notpad and questions. thanks in advance.

Database(UserInformation table)

userid/ username

Comment: What technology will you use for database access? ADO.NET, EntitFramework, Linq To Sql, Entity Framework?

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you have problem with global vision of how your application will be organized. In WPF it is very common to use **Model-View-ViewModel** pattern. I think that [this famous MSDN article by Josh Smith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) will be helpful for you. You can find demo application code [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mag200902MVVM/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=2026).

Hope it helps.